# Laravel: Retrieve relational data

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

**Commodity:**

```
public function variations() {
    return $this->hasMany( CommodityVariation::class )->with( 'unit' );
}
```

**Recipe:**

```
public function commodity_variations() {
    return $this->belongsToMany( CommodityVariation::class, 'recipe_commodity_variations' )->with( 'commodity' )->withTimestamps();
}
```

**CommodityVariation:**

```
public function commodity() {
    return $this->belongsTo( Commodity::class )->with( 'variations', 'allergens' );
}

public function recipes() {
    return $this->belongsToMany( Recipe::class, 'recipe_commodity_variations' )->withTimestamps();
}
```

**What I'm looking for:**
I would like to get all recipes that use/have this specific commodity, but I've to go through my commodity_variations to find the relation between recipe and commodity. This is because recipe is linked to commodity variations and commodity variations is linked to commodity.

So what I've build so far, is this, but it just returns 50 recipes regardleess of what commodity_id I enter. For instance if I write 100000 instead of $commodity->id this returns 50 recipes aswell.

```
$recipe = $department->recipes()->with(["commodity_variations" => function($q) use ( $commodity ) {
    $q->where('commodity_variations.commodity_id', '=', $commodity->id);
}])->get();
```

I really can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. I might be misunderstanding some basic stuff on how these relations work.

**Edit:**
here is another example

```
            $commodity_variations = $recipe->commodity_variations()->with( [
                'commodity' => function ( $query ) use ( $commodity ) {
                    $query->where( 'commodities.id', $commodity->id );
                }
            ] )->get();
```

Should return only the commodity variations that have commodity->id = 11, but it returns all. Like it's completely ignoring the where part of my query.

Comment: Not sure what you mean but you can fetch nested relations by using a dot within the `with` method: `$department->recipes()->with('commodity.variations')->get()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this once.

```
        $commodity_variations = $recipe->whereHas('commodity_variations' ,
             function ( $query ) use ( $commodity ) {
                return $query->where( 'commodity_variations.commodity_id', $commodity->id );
            }
         )->get();
```

Also refer this: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#querying-relations

Comment: return $query->where( 'commodity_variations.commodity_id', $commodity->id ); works. Thanks. Could you please change it and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working solution. Made a new model taking care of the many to many relation between recipe and commodityvariation.

```
class RecipeCommodityVariations extends Model {

    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'recipe_commodity_variations';
}
```

Query:

```
$recipeCommodityVariations = RecipeCommodityVariations::whereIn( 'recipe_id', $department->recipes()->pluck( 'recipe_id' ) )->whereIn( 'commodity_variation_id', $commodity->variations()->pluck( 'id' ) )->pluck( 'recipe_id' )
```

What troubles me, is that I feel like I'm doing it wrong... It's pretty annoying.